# F Test for seeing whether different groups have same model

Tags: self-study, econometrics

I'm studying for a final in econometrics, and I'm not sure I follow the reasoning in one of our practice problems. This data set is based on household expenditure surveys.
$
CLOTPCT: \text{% of expenditures spent on clothing.} \\
SIZE: \text{# of people in the family} \\
SIZEAM: \text{# of adult males in family} \\
SIZEAF: \text{# of adult females in family} \\ 
SIZEJM: \text{# of junior males in family} \\
SIZEJF: \text{# of junior females in the family}\\
SIZEIN: \text{# of infants below the age of 2} \\
HSG: \text{Dummy variable on whether the head of household is a high school graduate }\\
COLL: \text{Dummy variable on whether the head of household is a college graduate}\\
EXP: \text{Amount of expenditures by family }\\
$

The question is:
$$\text{Test the null hypothesis that all ages and genders of people have the same effect on CLOTPCT}$$

We're supposed to do an F test between two regressions
$$CLOTPCT = \beta_0+\beta_1SIZEAM+\beta_2SIZEAF+\beta_3SIZEJM+\beta_4SIZEJF+\beta_5SIZEIN+\beta_6 HSG+\beta_7COLL+\beta_8EXP +u$$

vs
$$CLOTPCT = \alpha+\beta_1SIZE+\beta_2 HSG+\beta_3COLL+\beta_4EXP +e$$

I thought the null hypothesis would be:
$$H_0: \beta_1=\beta_2=\beta_3=\beta_3=\beta_4$$

Also not sure what the alternative should be, but I have no idea why the above F test is the correct way to approach this.

Comment: (1) Is it intentional that $\beta_3$ appears twice in the first regression? (2) What is "SIZE"?  Would it be the sum of the five separate SIZE* variables?  If so, how does your second model compare to the first when you plug that formula in for SIZE? BTW, it can be confusing to use $\beta_0$ etc. to refer to the *different* parameters in two *distinct* models.  You might be better off using, say, $\alpha_0$ etc to denote the parameters in one of them so you can clearly distinguish them all.

Comment: Oops sorry, corrected it. The thing I'm not sure is why does the F test between the two regressions test that hypothesis? Substituting SIZE for all the other ones will give them all the coefficient of $\beta_1$, but I don't what F testing the two models does exactly